# Power BI DAX : Divide 2 Rows Data to derive 3rd Row

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have table with the data as shown below :

Region,State,Date,Metric,Amount
R1,S1,Jan 01 2010, Sales,28223
R1,S1,Jan 01 2010, Qty, 230
R1,S2,Jan 01 2010, Sales,28223
R1,S2,Jan 01 2010, Qty, 230

We would like to have a third metric to be computed as a separate row. When the user tries to build a report at a Region Level , then it should aggregate the data and show all the 3 metrics ( 2 Available and 3rd computed)

3rd Metric formula - Price Per Qty: Value for Metric Sales/Value for Metric Qty.

We would like to see the data in the format below :

Region,State,Date,Metric,Amount
R1,S1,Jan 01 2010, Sales,28223
R1,S1,Jan 01 2010, Qty, 230
R1,S1,Jan 01 2010, Price Per Qty, 28223/230
R1,S2,Jan 01 2010, Sales,3452
R1,S2,Jan 01 2010, Qty, 122
R1,S2,Jan 01 2010, Price Per Qty, 3452/122

Suppose the user tries to build a report at Region Level , then the report should be  as shown below :

```
Region,Metric,Amount
R1,Sales,sum(28223+3452)
R1,Qty,sum(230+122)
R1,Price Per Qty , Sum(28223+3452)/sum(230+122)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done without transforming the table. The 1st step is to pivot on `Metric` column. Choose the `Amount` column as values and click OK. Apply the changes.

[image]

[image]

The 2nd step is to create a measure to calculate `Price per Qty`. Here's the DAX.

```
Price per Qty = DIVIDE(SUM(Metrics[ Sales]),SUM(Metrics[ Qty]),BLANK())
```

The 3rd step is to use a Matrix visual instead of Table visual. Matrix visual allows you to show values on rows. The option is under `Format` pane -> `Values` -> `Show on rows`. You can use +/- icons to expand/collapse to the desired level and the metrics will be calculated for that level.

[image]